# Spigot /execute <player name> not working

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I'm having an issue with spigot. When I type the command `execute as @s run say Hey`, it works. But if I try with a player name: `execute as NooTChhMC run say Hey`, it doesn't even send feedback.

Version: spigot 1.16.1

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you got this issue sorted. If you happen to be a developer perhaps in the future you could debug this issue as I can only see it being an issue with either your client-side session (I've personally had some weird issues on 1.16 with my client-session being invalid but allowing me to connect to servers and causing mayhem) or some sort of server-side error.

In any case, you should always just make sure you log out and into the server and if that doesn't work, restart the server. After that making sure 100% that you typed in the command feel free to post it to Stack Overflow or probably more helpful to yourself the Spigot Forums or Bukkit Forums dedicated to Spigot and Bukkit coding.

If you'd like any more help with your server, feel free to leave a reply and I'll @ some of my social media.

Kind regards,
Luke L.

Comment: I imagined it would :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a **typo** in your nickname.
I had used it myself on spigot 1.16.1, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah... spigot just didn't want me to use the command like that. It's working now.